# Azure Cosmos DB Error with Private Link and Private Endpoint "Failed to refresh the collection list. Please try again later"

Tags: terraform, azure-cosmosdb, terraform-provider-azure

I have enabled Private Endpoint for my Azure Cosmos DB. Everytime i go to Cosmos, i see a Red Flag on top which says : `Failed to refresh the collection list. Please try again later`.
We use Terraform to deploy code.

Also i don't see any container being created even though i have the below code in Terraform

```
resource "azurerm_cosmosdb_sql_container" "default" {
  resource_group_name = module.resourcegroup.resource_group.name

  account_name  = azurerm_cosmosdb_account.default.name
  database_name = azurerm_cosmosdb_sql_database.default.name
  name          = "cosmosdb_container"

  partition_key_path = "/definition/id"
  throughput         = 400
}
```

Any idea what can i do to fix this. I don't see these issues when the Cosmos is not behind a Private Endpoint and Private link

My TF Code is provided below :

```
resource "azurerm_cosmosdb_account" "default" {
  resource_group_name = module.resourcegroup.resource_group.name
  location            = var.location

  name                                  = module.name_cosmosdb_account.location.cosmosdb_account.name_unique
  tags                                  = module.resourcegroup.resource_group.tags
  public_network_access_enabled         = false
  network_acl_bypass_for_azure_services = true
  enable_automatic_failover             = true
  is_virtual_network_filter_enabled     = true

  offer_type = "Standard"
  kind       = "GlobalDocumentDB"

  consistency_policy {
    consistency_level       = "Session"
    max_interval_in_seconds = 5
    max_staleness_prefix    = 100
  }

  geo_location {
    location          = module.resourcegroup.resource_group.location
    failover_priority = 0
  }
  geo_location {
    location          = "eastus2"
    failover_priority = 1
  }
}

resource "azurerm_cosmosdb_sql_database" "default" {
  resource_group_name = module.resourcegroup.resource_group.name

  account_name = azurerm_cosmosdb_account.default.name
  name         = "cosmosdb_db"
  throughput   = 400
}


resource "azurerm_cosmosdb_sql_container" "default" {
  resource_group_name = module.resourcegroup.resource_group.name

  account_name  = azurerm_cosmosdb_account.default.name
  database_name = azurerm_cosmosdb_sql_database.default.name
  name          = "cosmosdb_container"

  partition_key_path = "/definition/id"
  throughput         = 400
}
```

Comment: Hello Ansuman, i have changed the setting and enabled the checkbox for "Allow access from Azure Portal". But i still don't see the containers and still that "Failed to refresh" message is appearing again and again. Any idea why this is so?

Comment: If i go to Data Explorer, i see SQL API and then cosmosdb_db underneath that. But the overview is still showing that message "Failed to refresh the collection list. Please try again later"

Comment: Can you please share the code which you have used for creating the cosmosdb ? Or are you using the same code that I have provided?

Comment: No i am using my own code. I pasted the code in the main question now. Please take a look. For the Pvt Endpoint for CosmosDB we are using our own module

Comment: Sure will take a look and get back to you and could please provide the modules that you are using for above code that you have provided I will need to use that too .

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/237377/discussion-between-ansumanbal-mt-and-pallab).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even with the error from Portal the container and resources are being created from terraform . You can use `Data explorer` to see the database and container created from terraform.

**Test:**

**Terraform code:**

```
provider "azurerm" {
    features{}
}
data "azurerm_resource_group" "rg" {
  name     = "resourcegroup"
}

resource "azurerm_virtual_network" "example" {
  name                = "cosmos-network"
  address_space       = ["10.0.0.0/16"]
  location            = data.azurerm_resource_group.rg.location
  resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
}

resource "azurerm_subnet" "example" {
  name                 = "cosmos-subnet"
  resource_group_name  = data.azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
  virtual_network_name = azurerm_virtual_network.example.name
  address_prefixes     = ["10.0.1.0/24"]

  enforce_private_link_endpoint_network_policies = true
}
resource "azurerm_cosmosdb_account" "example" {
  name                = "ansuman-cosmosdb"
  location            = data.azurerm_resource_group.rg.location
  resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
  offer_type          = "Standard"
  kind                = "GlobalDocumentDB"

  consistency_policy {
    consistency_level       = "BoundedStaleness"
    max_interval_in_seconds = 10
    max_staleness_prefix    = 200
  }

  geo_location {
    location          = data.azurerm_resource_group.rg.location
    failover_priority = 0
  }
}

resource "azurerm_private_endpoint" "example" {
  name                = "cosmosansuman-endpoint"
  location            = data.azurerm_resource_group.rg.location
  resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
  subnet_id           = azurerm_subnet.example.id

  private_service_connection {
    name                           = "cosmosansuman-privateserviceconnection"
    private_connection_resource_id = azurerm_cosmosdb_account.example.id
    subresource_names              = [ "SQL" ]
    is_manual_connection           = false
  }
}

resource "azurerm_cosmosdb_sql_database" "example" {
  name                = "ansuman-cosmos-mongo-db"
  resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
  account_name        = azurerm_cosmosdb_account.example.name
  throughput          = 400
}

resource "azurerm_cosmosdb_sql_container" "default" {
  resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
  account_name  = azurerm_cosmosdb_account.example.name
  database_name = azurerm_cosmosdb_sql_database.example.name
  name          = "cosmosdb_container"

  partition_key_path = "/definition/id"
  throughput         = 400
}
```

**Output:**

[image]

[image]

[image]

---

**Update:** As per the Discussion , the error `Failed to refresh the collection list. Please try again later.` is by-default in your case as you have disabled public network access to the cosmosdb account while creation. If its set to disabled, public network traffic will be blocked even before the private endpoint is created.

**So, for this error the possible solutions will be :**

- Enable public network traffic to access the account while creating the cosmosdb account from terraform. As , Even you set it to true after the private endpoint is set for cosmosdb , public access to cosmosdb will be automatically disabled , if you go to the firewalls and virtual networks you can see allow access from all networks is grayed out . So, you can check  `allow access from portal` and `add your current IP` there to get access only for your public network as shown below.(note : as its bydefault set to true so you don't need to add `public_network_access_enabled = true` in code.)

[image]

[image]

- You can use Data Explorer to check the containers which has been already verified by you .
- You can create a VM on the same vnet where the endpoint is residing and
  connect the cosmosdb from inside the VM on portal itself. You can refer this [Microsoft Document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/private-link/tutorial-private-endpoint-cosmosdb-portal?bc=/azure/cosmos-db/breadcrumb/toc.json&toc=/azure/cosmos-db/toc.json) for more details.